# Memory leak in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, memory-leaks

My web application works in tomcat server, but after som time memory usage start to grow and grow until server goes down.

This happens on live only and it did not happened when I try to reproduce this situation locally. I tried to profile remotely with JProfiler, and found a lot of byte[] before server went down. The server goes down 2-3minutes after it starts to take more and more memory so I can't see what items use byte[] in code because Heap walk take more time (web app is really big).

I will be grateful for any help or suggestion.

Comment: Add `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath="/tmp"` to your `java` arguments, wait for the dump and import in JProfiler

Answer (score 0):

suggestion: put a few memory usage dumps in your classes where are the caching storage fields with HashMap, Vector ( or unsynchronized versions of those collections) usually those keep references. Than I would put a plus url, which will dump my variable, like:

Runtime.getRuntime().callMemoryFunctionForgotName(): used memory is  270mb... for eg.
-here you should see WHEN is growing, over the time there are actions and one of those has leak.

- when you have detected the link43 with action9 will produce memory leak than is easy :)
- just add a few hashMap.count() or size()  (forgot this too , lol) to logg, than you will see which one of 20 collection is increasing and not decreasing. Hopefully you have acces to live server logs.

So I would do in 2 steps.